# Premier Pro: why does Encoding leads to pinkinsh' green lines?

Tags: video, encoding

so from past few days i'm working on a footage which i have sped up for time-lapse the source is actually multiple footage, some where inverted so i rotated them.

Anyways, in the final product i'm trying to add some video transition effects and so fourth.

however when i try to encode it, the final video shows me these ultra exaggerating lines..

[image]

i have cropped the image from left and right sides (and in some cases top-bottom for the inverted ones), and edge feathered which i don't think is the reason right?

my sequence setting are.

[image]

I'm using `CC 2018 version` and i'm trying to encode in `H.264` format. not using hardware acceleration (i have AMD), maximum render quality doesn't effect it, i have tested it, and my source is also 29.97 fps (does the speeding up affects it?).

so what could be the reason for this any guesses guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try updating to the latest version of Premier Pro. If this doesn't work then try changing the file format, codec, or try disabling openCL rendering. Attempt these one at a time to see what effect each one causes.

Comment: yea, actually the issue was with the openCL rendering, it's really sad that you cannot do some immersive transitions without openCL, as i have a radeon M430 i doesn't support the GPU rendering that much, i guess that's why nvidia is preferred. thank for the suggestion though.